# Symantec Endpoint Protection compatibility with Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS

Tags: compatibility, antivirus

Is Symantec Endpoint Protection compatible with Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS with kernel version 3.19.0-80-generic ?

Server:
Symantec Endpoint Protection Manager version - 12.1.5(12.1 RU5)
Operating System - Windows 2008 R2

Client:
Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS
kernel - 3.19.0-80-generic

Comment: Seems answered at https://support.symantec.com/en_US/article.TECH223240.html

Comment: Is kernel version should be same as mentioned in article or Is it supports for updated kernel also. In article SEP 14.X supports for Ubuntu 14.04 with kernel version 3.13.0-63-generic or 
3.13.0-139-generic (Added for 14 RU1 MP2) but my kernel version is 3.19.0-80-generic.